# Is calculating margin of error still useful for my sample that was convenience sampled?

Tags: error, survey-sampling

I've recently conducted a survey of 201 students and some staff at my College. I've read some discussion about using margin of error (MOE) for non-probability samples and one seemingly good point I've read is that:

"The margin of error around a convenience sample is the margin of error around a similarly drawn convenience population. If you are interviewing people in an upscale mall on a Thursday afternoon, you are drawing a margin of error around an estimate for a population of people who agreed to be interviewed in this upscale mall on a Thursday afternoon."

The case he used as an example is similar to the case of sampling at a university. So can I or should I still calculate and present the margin of error in my data analysis?

Comment: That argument is nonsense.  What is a convenience population and why would emulating it lead to a margin of error?

Comment: Alright. So should I still calculate and present a margin of error for my sample in my results section?

Comment: Didn't I indicate that it would be wrong?  No you should not.

Comment: Hmm...Are there any inferential statistics that I can still calculate and present? What about the confidence intervals?